# Get correct sheet in spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is how my Spreadsheet is now
[image: spreadsheet].

Right now, I need to get to correct sheet by name and change color of some cells, given sheet ID and sheet name. However, I am stuck at how to get the correct sheet.

My code now:

```
   $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
   $spreadSheetId = 'my_spread_sheet_id';
   $spreadSheetName = 'my_sheet_day';
   $sheetInfo = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId)->getSheets();
```

I thought I can try getSheetsByName but it doesn't work. Looking at [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_Sheet.html) does not have information on how to get sheet information either. Am I taking the wrong way ?

Comment: Does this helps https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet.html

Comment: @Adi I looked at that but still have 0 clue. Tried getSheets above and thought I could have a list of Sheets to take a look at the name but not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the sheet ID from the sheet name.
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API with googleapis for php.
- You have already been able to get values from Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, to retrieve the object of `properties` from each sheet using the method of "spreadsheets.get" in Sheets API. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadSheetId = 'my_spread_sheet_id';
$spreadSheetName = 'my_sheet_day';

// Retrieve the objects from Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.
$sheets = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadSheetId, ["fields" => "sheets(properties)"])->getSheets();

// Create an object for searching the sheet ID from the sheet name.
$obj = array();
foreach ($sheets as $i => $sheet) {
    $property = $sheet -> getProperties();
    $obj[$property -> getTitle()] = $property -> getSheetId();
}

// Retrieve the sheet ID from the sheet name.
$sheetId = $obj[$spreadSheetName];
echo $sheetId;
```

- In this sample script, the fields of `sheets(properties)` is used. I think that in this case, you can also use `$sheets = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadSheetId)->getSheets();`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the sheet ID. So If I want to change the color of the cell on the sheet, is it possible with Google_Service_Sheets ? I think there are some answers with Google_Service_Sheets_Request